# Conflicts When Installing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted to install rails on my Mac. I ran

```
sudo gem rails install
```

during installation two things happened:

1. I got this message: "railties's executable "rails" conflicts with /usr/bin/rails Overwrite the executable? [yN]". I responded by 'y'. I found later some people don't recommended that way of rails installation. They recommend RVM for that. I don't know now if what I did will cause future problems. What should I do now?
2. During installation I got many messages that look like this:`unable to convert "\xCA" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, skipping`. I found some people suggesting to run `gem update` to which I got similar UTF-8  messages and other conflicts like `rake's executable "rake" conflicts with /usr/bin/rake
   Overwrite the executable? [yN]` I wrote 'N' this time, as I am not sure how to proceed. Any recommendations?

Comment: Unless you are specifically running your user account as a non-admin, you should never need to use sudo to install a gem. Even if you are a local admin you will have less permissions than sudo, which will cause problems when you go to actually use the gem.

Comment: Installing rails from RVM solved the UTF-8 messages problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Don't Overwrite Your System Ruby

Never, ever overwrite your system Ruby. You will only cause yourself pain and suffering.

Assuming you haven't already hosed your system, install a version manager like [RVM](https://rvm.io/), [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), or [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) and install your rubies and gems (including Ruby on Rails) from within the version manager.

Comment: Unluckily, I have already overwritten my system Rails, is there a fix?

Comment: Technically, he is not overwriting his system Ruby, but rather using the system Ruby. The messages were to overwrite the `rails` and `rake` executables.

Comment: @salah, if you install RVM (or similar), you can set this as your default `ruby` to use. By doing this, your system will be completely unaware that you have a system `ruby` version. Instead, the `ruby` from your version manager will be used. It wouldn't matter how badly you messed up your system `ruby` as the version manager would take precedence.

Comment: @kobaltz, so should I uninstall Rails, and then proceed by installing RVM and installing Rails again to avoid overwritten my system files? what about the UTF-8 messages that I got during installation?

Comment: Uninstall rails only if you want to save the disk space. It will not conflict with your version manager.

Comment: @kobaltz what is the right way to uninstall rails then? because when I run gem uninstall rails I get "You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory".